# Launching the iPhone maps application from your own code

Tags: iphone

How to Launch the iPhone maps application from our own code

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps"]];

I tried this code,but its coming in browser.Its not opening in the iPhones Default map app...
I want my code to display the iPhone default map app to come up after existing the application which is being run.

Answer (score 0):

use MKmapView to show map in Application instead of launching the Browser.